# Apply Min or Max function to arrays when NA exist in R

Tags: r, max, na

I have a question looks simple but really drives me crazy. I really need your help.

First lets generate some data.frame

```
a<-c(rep(1:2,2),NA,NA)
b<-c(rep(NA,3),3,4,NA)
df<-cbind(a,b)
```

This will give a table as:

```
      a  b
[1,]  1 NA
[2,]  2 NA
[3,]  1 NA
[4,]  2  3
[5,] NA  4
[6,] NA NA
```

Now I need a third column which will be:

1. When both a and b are not NA, return the max value in both.
2. When one of them are not NA, return the non-NA number
3. When both them are NA, return NA.

To sum up, I am looking for the result like this:

```
      a  b  c
[1,]  1 NA  1
[2,]  2 NA  2
[3,]  1 NA  1
[4,]  2  3  3
[5,] NA  4  4
[6,] NA NA NA
```

I tried `df$c<-max(df$a,df$b)`and obviously this doesn't work and give me:

`Error in df$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Could someone help me please? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try `pmax` after converting the dataset ('df' is 'matrix') to 'data.frame'

```
cbind(df, c=do.call(`pmax`, c(as.data.frame(df), list(na.rm=TRUE))))
#      a  b  c
#[1,]  1 NA  1
#[2,]  2 NA  2
#[3,]  1 NA  1
#[4,]  2  3  3
#[5,] NA  4  4
#[6,] NA NA NA
```

If you need the "min" value for each row, replace `pmax` with `pmin`.
To create a 'data.frame', you could use

```
df <- data.frame(a, b)
```

`cbind` get the output as 'matrix'.  `$` operator won't work with 'matrix', so it is better to use `[`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "regular" `max` function:

```
df <- cbind(df, c = apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, max(x, na.rm=T))))

df
#      a  b  c
#[1,]  1 NA  1
#[2,]  2 NA  2
#[3,]  1 NA  1
#[4,]  2  3  3
#[5,] NA  4  4
#[6,] NA NA NA
```

Comment: May I ask what is the `1` in the apply stand for?

Comment: @user3797905, it tells `R` to apply the function by `row`. To apply the function by `column`, you would have to set this parameter to `2`